# How to get veevr video thumbnail from video ID

Tags: video, embed, thumbnails

I've been having trouble getting the veevr video thumbnails from it's video ID. I've seen other sites implement it but I have no clue on how to do it myself.

For example the ID of the video is this `dcSLCspLf`

Thumbnail Image link: `http://hwcdn.net/j3v8m4w2/cds/images/video_thumbs/smaller_thumbs/b40b78b3c7814bbe83bf8298976e6ee8.jpg`

As you can see none of it really matches, so I was hoping you guys could help out.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there's no proper API for this veevr site which allows you to fetch things like thumbnails in a cleaner manner (XML, JSON or similar)? From studying the page source for, e.g., http://veevr.com/videos/dcSLCspLf, I see that there is an `img` tag with id="vid-thumb". One hack to solve your problem might be to fetch the page and find that one img tag, following the link and downloading the image. The linked image (http://hwcdn.net/j3v8m4w2/cds/www/images/videos/thumbs/154413.jpg) isn't exactly thumbnail-sized (640x352). However, it might be more appropriate than the image you found as the "true" thumbnail which is squished into a 4:3 aspect ratio and looks weird/wrong.

So you might be able to automatically download the larger "thumbnail" and resize it to a better resolution.